# Angular 11 - mat-sort is not working in ng-modal table

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, ng-modal

mat-sort and paginator is not working in ng-modal table. But outside modal it is working properly. Are there any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The problem is that, when you try asign the mat-sort, the mat-sort is not reachable -because really it's not displayed-. You need asign the mat-sort **after** displayed. If you're using mat-dialog, when you open use a setTimeout(). You can think setTimeout as you say to Angular: "After render, don't forget execute this instructions"</strike>

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal}
});
setTimeout(()=>{ //<--here you say to Angular the sort
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
})
```

If you're using ng-bootstrap modal

```
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
    setTimeout(()=>{ //<--here you say to Angular the sort
       this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    })
  }
```

NOTE: remember that, as the mat-table is not visible all the time the mat-sort ViewChild should be like

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

NOT use `{static true}` -static true it's used only if the element is always displayed in the component-

**Update** really the solution proposed not work. Inside a template the "viewChild are not accesible. So the only I get is create a fool directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[fool]',
  exportAs: 'fool'
})
export class FoolDirective implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      (this.table.dataSource as any).sort=this.sort
    })
  }
  constructor(@Optional() private sort:MatSort,@Optional() private table:MatTable<any>){}
}
```

So, we only need add this directive to our table

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource"
  matSort fool
  class="mat-elevation-z8">
 ....
</table>
```

See the [stackblitz][1]

**Update2** For add a paginator, the thing is more complex. My idea is improve our directive fool, adding a MatPaginator as Optional and send as output

```
export class FoolDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() paginatorLoaded:EventEmitter<MatPaginator>=new EventEmitter<MatPaginator>()
  ngOnInit()
  {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      if (this.table && this.sort)
        (this.table.dataSource as any).sort=this.sort
      if (this.paginator)
        this.paginatorLoaded.emit(this.paginator)
    })
  }
  constructor(@Optional() private sort:MatSort,@Optional() private table:MatTable<any>,@Optional() private paginator:MatPaginator){}
}
```

Then, the only is, when add the Paginator write

```
<mat-paginator  fool 
         (paginatorLoaded)="dataSource.paginator=$event"
....>
</mat-paginator>
```

The only is change the .css adding in styles.css

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 9000;
}
```

else the select of number of pages don't show -it is showed, but is under the popup

NOTE: Really I don't like so much these work-around, perhaf is time to re-think and use another popup -e.g. the material- or use the ngb-bootstrap modal with components nor with template.
[1]: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbadro?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffool.directive.ts

Comment: I tried it and it's not working. Here is the stackblitz link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8afc1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: My Faul!! Sorry, I update the answer (It's the only solution I can get it)

Comment: Thank you so much for the updated answer. But I have one last question. How do I this with paginator? As I've understand it follows the same principle as sort but in this case it's not working. This is my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4epuhe?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffool.directive.ts

Comment: after think about the problem, I update again the answer